# NetLogo issues on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I am running NetLogo 6.0.2 on a Windows PC with a recently updated windows 10 OS. Prior to the update I had a model, I have developed for my research, running perfectly fine. Since the update, Netlogo is no longer able to recognise file pathways I have in place for calling in data needed for the model to run. The model was originally written on a Mac so when I initially put the model into the Windows PC all I needed to do was change the file destinations and convention ('/' for '\' etc.) and this meant the model worked perfectly fine. I am wondering if anyone else has had recent issues with NL on Windows 10 that are along the lines of this (please say there are!) and if so, how you worked around the issue.

All and any help or pointers would be more than greatly appreciated!

[NL & Windows 10 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUQZd.png)

Comment: I haven't seen any reports of file path issues on Windows 10 with NetLogo 6.  Do you have more details on what isn't working?  Are you seeing an error?  Are you constructing absolute paths or relative paths?  An example of the kind of file path you're making might let others try it out.  Are you trying to get the data with the built in file primitives or the `csv` extension or some other way?

Comment: Hi Jasper, Thanks for the response. I've added an image of the error message NL is giving me with the syntax highlighted and the file path in red. for some reason NL will only recognise the file paths with '//.' Could this also possibly be linked to the 'one drive' section of the file path? Thanks again, hope the image answers enough of your questions?

Comment: Hey Tom, I was able to reproduce the error, so thank you for the screen shot.  I was also able to work around the error by removing the leading and trailing spaces in the `mask` variable; so `"C:\path\to\file.asc"` not `"_C:\path\to\file.asc_"`  Let me know if that works for you.

Side note for StackOverflow etiquette - it's usually better to copy/paste code than screenshots, especially [properly formatted code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).  That helps others quickly grab snippets to check/test.

Comment: Jasper, it would seem that this obvious, slight and highly frustrating oversight was indeed the issue! Sometimes, it just needs another pair of eyes to see the obvious and your help with this has been greatly appreciated. SO etiquette is also noted for future reference. Thanks again, Tom.

Comment: No problem, glad it's working for you again!